# How to list all member variables of a class inherited from QObject in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Let's suppose I have some class like

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyClass (QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass ();
    int var1;
    QString var2;
};
```

What I want to do is to print its member variables like var1 and var2 in a loop. Can QMetaObject help me here?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't, because Qt's metadata system only provides the following information about a class:

- names, signatures and lookup-by-address of member functions declared as signals, slots, or invokable,
- class name and inheritance,
- named properties (declared with `Q_PROPERTY`),
- class information (declared with `Q_CLASSINFO`).

Specifically, `moc` ignores any other members, and generates no metadata for them, as that would be wasteful.

It is possible to patch up moc and metadata format to add other kinds of information - those aren't big changes. Feel free to look at moc sources and `QMetaData` to figure it out.